# WSL -- invalid option

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

Everywhere I see advice to run WSL commands as

```
wsl --user root linuxcommand
```

however I only get error saying

```
/bin/bash: --: invalid option
```

Why does my WSL pick up "--"?

```
wsl linuxcommand
```

works just fine, except when I need to elevate privileges and I get permission denied, for which I would seem to need "--user root" switch.

Comment: Where are you seeing this exactly?

Comment: cmd. https://i.imgur.com/zcykXiq.png

Comment: That isn’t what I asked for.  Where are you reading that commands is even valid?

Comment: Well for example here: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/127608-run-windows-subsystem-linux-wsl-distro-windows-10-a.html (option two). Seen it on stackexchange as well.

Comment: Ok it seems that it is for 19.03 version, it's 18.03 on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Everywhere I see advice to run WSL commands as …, however, I only get error saying that -- was an invalid option.  I am running Windows 10 version 1803.

The feature you are attempting to use is only supported on Windows 10 version 1903.

> Starting with Windows 10 build 18342 (19H1) and Windows 10 build 18836
>   (20H1), Microsoft added some new commands that will give you more
>   functionality when using wsl.exe. The commands that existed inside of
>   wslconfig.exe have been added to wsl.exe to allow you to configure
>   your distros more easily.

In order to set the default user you would have to use the command `ubuntu config --default-user root` if you were running a WSL instance on Windows 10 version 1803.

> WSL Config (wslconfig.exe) is a command-line tool for managing Linux distributions running on the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). It lets you list available distributions, set a default distribution, and uninstall distributions.
>   While WSL Config is helpful for settings that span or coordinate distributions, each Linux distribution independently manages its own configurations. To see distribution-specific commands, run [distro.exe] /?. For example ubuntu /?.

Source:

- [Manage and configure Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config)
- [How Do I Reset A Manual Installation Of Windows Subsystem For Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/1440045/how-do-i-reset-a-manual-installation-of-windows-subsystem-for-linux/1440062#1440062)
- [How to Run a Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) Distro in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/127608-run-windows-subsystem-linux-wsl-distro-windows-10-a.html)
- [How to change the default user name in WSL?](https://superuser.com/questions/1266881/how-to-change-the-default-user-name-in-wsl/1266977#1266977)