# Change default WSL 2 user after export/import

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I'm trying to move my WSL2 "distribution" to another hard drive with more space. I've performed the following:

```
wsl --export Ubuntu-20.04 ubuntu-20_04-export.tar
wsl --import Ubuntu-20.04-reimported D:\tools\wsl-ubuntu-20_04 .\ubuntu-20_04-export.tar
```

and I've changed my WinTerm configuration to set the new distro as the default profile. I've also set the distro as the default distro with `wsl -s`. And I've unregistered the old distro. But when I start up the new WSL distro in WinTerm, it now signs me in as root. As in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1266881/how-to-change-the-default-user-name-in-wsl), I've tried to run the following:

```
ubuntu2004.exe config --default-user <existing-user-name>
```

But new sessions started with WinTerm still start as root by default. `ubuntu2004.exe` doesn't seem to affect the new distro but instead installs yet another distro in order to set the default user there. The following works fine with the new distro:

```
wsl -u <existing-user-name>
```

But how do I change the default user of the new distro?

Comment: One of the problems caused by this is that my VS Code WSL extension [connecting to WSL as root](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/3631) and saving new files and such as root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few weeks later, I found a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61474401/how-to-change-the-default-user-after-import-old-wsl-tar-package) on StackOverflow (not sure of the protocol for cross-site duplicates...).

The answer that worked for me was adding the following to my distribution's `/etc/wsl.conf`:

```
[user]
default=yourusername
```

Comment: See this updated and more complete post: [How to set default user for manually installed WSL distro?](https://superuser.com/a/1627461/771766)